# how to call button click event from codebehind using c# asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Trying to call button click event from JavaScript function but how can I do so from code behind?

```
   if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
       string script = "window.onload = function() { 
            PopulateTextBox('" + dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString() 
            + "','" + dt.Rows[0]["surname"].ToString() + "','" 
            + dt.Rows[0]["email"].ToString() 
            + "','" + dt.Rows[0]["phone"].ToString() + "'); 
          };
          //--------trying to trigger Btnformsubmit_Click click event here----------
        ";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "", script, true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "ShowPopup();", 
        true);
            
   }
   protected void Btnformsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            
   }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to trigger an event? Why not just run code that the event would run?

Comment: the code that you have here did not help at all. Can you please make a minimal example on what you actually try to do ?

Comment: This looks like WinForms, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is WebForms, here is one way of doing it:

```
var scriptName = "ClickEventScript";
var type = this.GetType();

if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(type, scriptName))
{
    StringBuilder scriptBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    scriptBuilder.Append("<script type=text/javascript>");
    scriptBuilder.Append("document.getElementById('" + Btnformsubmit.ClientId + "').click();");
    scriptBuilder.Append("</script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(type, scriptName, scriptBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Please check the syntax. I wrote this in a hurry.